# Regarding Keras Tensorflow backend GPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am trying to run LSTM code on GPU. I have set `keras` back-end to tensorflow. I am aware that tensorflow will automatically run on GPU.  However i am still adding the below lines to make it run on GPU. Is there any other way I can confirm that it is using GPU? I am new to this learning, so your advice would really help me.

```python
import os
os.environ['CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER']='PCI_BUS_ID'
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = "0"
```

To disable/ mask GPU/ force to make it run on CPU, I do:

```python
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = " "
```

The available devices are :

```python
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

device_lib.list_local_devices()

Out[2]: 
[name: "/cpu:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 629258381829369248, name: "/gpu:0"
 device_type: "GPU"
 memory_limit: 324403200
 locality {
   bus_id: 1
 }
 incarnation: 7545755248924255940
 physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0"]
```

Comment: Try compare time (GPU vs CPU) with this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54661896/10418812

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Tensorflow backend in your case uses GPU, `device_lib.list_local_devices()` confirms that.

But, be aware of the side effect of using `list_local_devices()` though. It allocates all memory on GPU for the Tensorflow. That can mess things up if you are planning to run several scripts using GPU at once.

Here are the details on that: [#9374](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9374), [#8021](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8021).